# checking if a long sentence contains a short sentence from TextField, Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to search for a short sentence inside a long sentence ...

it is working fine with this demo:

```
        String a = 'from first day i was very good';
        String b = 'from first day';
        print(a.contains(b));
```

result : **true**

but when I use `TextField` to enter a short sentence and check it if is exciting in a long sentence ...
**`TextField` when I enter space between words doesn't show any result**

**Note**: this app in the Arabic language and doesn't work on an android and IOS ... in English worked well in the IOS simulator but doesn't work on an android phone.

my all code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:egyptian_ads_app/constant/constant.dart';
import 'package:egyptian_ads_app/pages/business_man_pages/business_man_page.dart';
import 'package:egyptian_ads_app/pages/starting_page/landing_service_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class ItemModel {
  ItemModel(
      {this.id,
      this.title,
      this.imagePath,
      this.about,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.traderId,
      this.type,
      this.city});

  int id;
  String title;
  String imagePath;
  String about;
  String phoneNumber;
  int traderId;
  String type;
  String city;

  factory ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new ItemModel(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['name'],
      imagePath: json["logo"]['url'],
      about: json['about'],
      phoneNumber: json['phone_number'],
      traderId: json['trader_id'],
      type: json['category']['type'],
      // city: json['city'],
    );
  }
}


class InstantSearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InstantSearchPageState createState() => _InstantSearchPageState();
}

class _InstantSearchPageState extends State<InstantSearchPage> {
  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  Future resultsLoaded;
  List<ItemModel> _allResults = [];
  List<ItemModel> _resultsList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _searchController.addListener(_onSearchChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.removeListener(_onSearchChanged);
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    resultsLoaded = getUserDetails();
  }

  getUserDetails() async {
    final String url = 'https://yallservice.com/api/v1/departments';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    var data = responseJson['data'];
    setState(() {
      for (Map user in data) {
        _allResults.add(ItemModel.fromJson(user));
      }
    });

    searchResultsList();
    return "complete";
  }

  _onSearchChanged() {
    searchResultsList();
  }

  searchResultsList() {
    List<ItemModel> showResults = [];

    if (_searchController.text != "") {
      for (var tripSnapshot in _allResults) {
        String title = tripSnapshot.about;
        print(title + title);
        if (title.contains(_searchController.text)) {
          showResults.add(tripSnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(),
        title: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _searchController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _resultsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: ListTile(
                      subtitle: Text(_resultsList[index].about),
                    ));
                // return Card(
                //   index: index,
                //   data: _resultsList,
                // );
              },
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem just by putting  `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,` to my `TextField`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the encoding of white spaces in RTL strings.

Try to trim the `TextField` text before you search for it.

### Special `trim` method

```
String trim(String string) {
  assert(string != null);
  final stringList = string.characters.toList();
  final whitespaces = ['8206', '8207', '32'];
  while (whitespaces.contains(stringList.last.runes.join()))
    stringList.removeLast();
  while (whitespaces.contains(stringList.first.runes.join()))
    stringList.remove(stringList.first);
  return stringList.join();
}
```

### Updated `searchResultsList`

```
searchResultsList() {
  List<ItemModel> showResults = [];
  if (_searchController.text != "") {
    for (var tripSnapshot in _allResults) {
      String title = tripSnapshot.about;
      if (title.contains(trim(_searchController.text))) {
        showResults.add(tripSnapshot);
      }
    }
  } else {
    showResults = List.from(_allResults);
  }
  setState(() {
    _resultsList = showResults;
  });
}
```

Ref: [Text fields' values do not get trimmed correctly when `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl` #68093](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68093)

---

### Improvement

Your search is currently case-sensitive. Maybe you should **make it case-insensitive**?

```
searchResultsList() {
  setState(() {
    _resultsList = _searchController.text.isNotEmpty
        ? _allResults
            .where((tripSnapshot) => tripSnapshot.about
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(trim(_searchController.text).toLowerCase()))
            .toList()
        : List.from(_allResults);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still the same error

Comment: Okay, what string are you looking for?

Comment: this one "من اول"

Comment: On my side: Without space, it works both with your code and mine. With space, it fails with your code but works fine with mine, after special trimming. Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error. Good luck!

Comment: thanks dear, actually i fixed the problem

Comment: What was the problem? Let's fully document it for future references.

Comment: I just added textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, to my TextField

Comment: now the problem happens just when changing languages inside textfiled, but without changing works well ... any tips or suggestion? please